# Reliable method to find byte size of int, float and double?

Tags: php, binary, pack

In the [pack](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php) function the byte size of ints `i`,`I`, floats `f` and doubles `d` are machine-dependent. How can I find out what these sizes are?

Comment: Found one method: `$sizeOfInt = strlen(decbin(~0))/8;`

Answer (score 0):

There's actually a constant called [`PHP_INT_SIZE`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php#constant.php-int-size). Floats should be the same size as an int, and doubles should be double that.